# How to use Mappings in AWS CloudFormation templates in nested stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapping, aws-cloudformation, nested-stack

Let's consider the following `Mappings` and `FindInMap` are used in the same AWS CloudFormation template. They will work.

Now, consider the `VpcIds` under `Mappings` are in the `master.yaml` template, and I am trying to create the `EgressOnlyInternetGateway` resource from the `nested.yaml` template  using those `Mappings` located in the `master.yaml` template.

How can I accomplish this?

```
# master.yaml
Mappings:
  VpcIds:
    us-east-1: 
      "123456789012": "vpc-00011122233344455"
      "234567890123": "vpc-11122233344455566"
    us-west-1: 
      "123456789012": "vpc-22233344455566677"
      "234567890123": "vpc-33344455566677788"


# nested.yaml
Resources:
  EgressOnlyInternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EgressOnlyInternetGateway
    Properties:
      VpcId: !FindInMap [VpcIds, !Ref "AWS::Region", !Ref "AWS::AccountId"]
```

**Update:** I am trying to create a resource `MyTestNestedSg` in `MyTestNestedStack` (`MyTestNestedStack.yaml`) using the a mapped parameter defined in `MyTestMasterStack` as showing below. I am getting error: `Parameter values specified for a template which does not require them`, against `MyTestNestedStack`.

How can I resolve this?

Please note that the resource `MyTestMasterSg` under `MyTestMasterStack` is just for the completeness.

```
# MyTestMasterStack.yaml
Mappings:
  VpcIds:
    us-east-1: 
      "123456789012": "vpc-00011122233344455" 
      "234567890123": "vpc-11122233344455566" 

Resources:
  MyTestNestedStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties: 
      Parameters: 
        VpcId: !FindInMap [VpcIds, !Ref "AWS::Region", !Ref "AWS::AccountId"]
      TemplateURL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_template_bucket_name/MyTestNestedStack.yaml"
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60

  MyTestMasterSg:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: "vpc-017a12485ad93e94a"
      GroupDescription: Testing resource creation wtih Mappings from the parent Stack
      GroupName: MyTestMasterSg
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 10.1.0.0/16
          FromPort: 80
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: 80

# MyTestNestedStack.yaml
Resources:
  MyTestNestedSg:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      GroupDescription: Testing resource creation wtih Mappings from the parent Stack
      GroupName: MyTestNestedSg
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 10.1.0.0/16
          FromPort: 8080
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: 8080
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this. You have to past resolved mapping values through [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html) to your `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack` resource.

Nested stacks should be self sufficient and they don't have access to the parent stack's parameters, mappings or resources. They can only work with data that you explicitly pass through `Parameters` of `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack` resource.

So in **parent** stack you would have to do:

```
MyNestedStack:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties: 
    Parameters: 
      VpcId : !FindInMap [VpcIds, !Ref "AWS::Region", !Ref "AWS::AccountId"]
  TemplateURL: String
```

**Update**

Your `MyTestNestedStack.yaml` is missing `Paramters`:

```
Parameters:
  
  VpcId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin for the prompt response. I followed this. Then I in `MyNestedStack` template, I used this reference `VpcId: !Ref VpcId` for creating a security group, but it failed with error `Parameter values specified for a template which does not require them.` against  `MyNestedStack`. Not sure if I am missing anything else.

Comment: @Rafiq Can you update your question with current state of your templates?

Comment: @Rafiq I updated the answer. Please have a look.